# Bundler having trouble with Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've cloned [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/faq/)'s master branch. My shared host is pretty new to Ruby on Rails. It won't let me run bundle install on any [gem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) that uses Git. The error:

```
Gemfile syntax error:
/home/soociali/rails_apps/Discus/Gemfile:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
...ctive_model_serializers', git: 'git://github.com/rails-api/a...
                          ^
```

The Gemfile: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/Gemfile

Comment: Also, it's using Bundler 1.2.4

Comment: replacing git with http protocol might help? ie `:git => 'http://....'`

Comment: IDK if the protocol matters, it's catching on :git so it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the file you are trying to run has a syntax that belongs to [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) 1.9 and you have an older version installed on your computer. You need to update it.

I don't know which OS are you using. *[Install Ruby 1.9 on CentOS](http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2010/11/06/install-ruby-1-9-centos.html)* is a guide for [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) and it might give you an idea on how to update it.

Or use [RVM](https://rvm.io/). It will make your life easier.